# Pass a variable into regex with string replace

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex, replace

I have a complicated regEx inside a string replace and I want to use a variable called "tagname" instead of the word Category, but I don't know how to do this.

```
$("textarea").val().replace(/\<Category\>(.*)\<\/Category\>/gi, "<Category>TextVariable</Category>");
```

I have tried something like this, but it didn't work in the first parameter.

```
$("textarea").val().replace("/\<" + tagname + "\>(.*)\<\/" + tagname "\>/gi", "<" + tagname + ">" + TextVariable + "</" + tagname + ">");
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `RegExp` constructor with a string pattern and flags:

```
var regex = new RegExp("<" + tagname + ">(.*)</" + tagname + ">", "gi");
$("textarea").val().replace(regex, "<" + tagname + ">" + TextVariable + "</" + tagname + ">");
```

Answer (score 6):

Use the `RegExp` constructor instead of regex literal.

```
var regex = new RegExp("<" + tagname + ">(.*)</" + tagname + ">", "gi");
$("textarea").val().replace(regex, "<" + tagname + ">" + 
   textVariable + "</" + tagname + ">");
```

you can simplify it as:

```
//capture the tag name:
var regex = new RegExp("<(" + tagname + ")>(.*)</" + tagname + ">", "gi");
$("textarea").val().replace(regex, "<$1>" + textVariable + "</$1>");
```

But bear in mind that [parsing xml/html with regex is a baaad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454)