# Jquery replace variable in all text syntax regex

Tags: javascript, regex, replace

This does not work because of the variable rep.  What is the correct syntax please?

```
var bigtext = 'testing test test test';
var rep = 'test'; 
bigtext = bigtext.replace(/rep/g, "MOO!");
```

I know the problem is with the regex part in the replace...but what is the correct way to write it?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Using a string variable as regular expression](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4786996/using-a-string-variable-as-regular-expression) and [Pass a variable into regex with string replace](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3139563/pass-a-variable-into-regex-with-string-replace?rq=1).

Comment: And what has jQuery got to do with basic regular expressions?

Comment: @David: epascarello's point was that this has nothing to do with jQuery. Regular expressions are a feature of the language itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You need to build a regex using the `RegExp` constructor:

```
var bigtext = 'testing test test test';
var rep = 'test'; 
var regex = new RegExp(rep, 'g');
bigtext = bigtext.replace(regex, "MOO!");
```

Documentation for this constructor can be seen on [the MDN page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). Note that you probably should make sure that any special characters in regular expressions (e.g. `[`) are escaped.

Comment: This works thanks!  and also thanks for the link to more information.